# Скролл по якорям

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу понять, как реализовать. 
Есть такая задача: если 100 пикселей блока с определенным классом попадает в видимость экрана при скролле страницы, то этот страница скроллится таким образом, что этот блок становится в самом вверху, иными словами "скролл по якорям", но не по клику на ссылку, а при попадании блока в видимость экрана. Желательно на jquery

Comment: Пример работы есть?

Comment: что-то типо плагина fullpage.js , но там при одном скролле нас кидает к следующему блоку, а я хочу сделать, чтобы при видимости 100пикс блока в экране кидало к нему, а скроллить можно как обычно